# Putting a div inside a link - area still clickable outside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I put a `div` inside an `a` tag **with an intent that only when I hover on the area occupied by the div**, I will get the hand cursor.

But it has a strange behavior.

You can see that the div has fixed dimensions (red border).

[image: see]

But even if I move the mouse *outside* the div, still the hand cursor appears.
Why?

**Like I said I basically want only the area inside the red border to be clickable.**

Here is the code:

```
const AppCustomIcon = (props) => {
    return (
        <a target="blank"

           href={props.url}>
        <div style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            border:"1px solid red",
            alignItems: "center"
        }}>


                <IconButton
                    style={{marginRight: 10}}
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                >
                    {props.icon}
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant={"body1"}>{props.text}</Typography>

        </div>
        </a>

    )
}
```

Comment: _“But even if I move mouse outside the div, still the hand cursor appears. Why?”_ - because that is default styling for `a` elements with a `href` attribute set …? You’ll need to overwrite this, if you don’t it for this particular link (and then add it again for the div that’s inside.)

Comment: @04FS Since I put a `div` *inside* an `a` my intention was that the cursor appears only when the mouse pointer is inside the div area - not outside it. I think you didn't understand the question

Comment: why do you need div in a? just add CSS to a, make it display block

Comment: @Roy.B That also appeared to be a solution, thanks. So having a div there has no benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor tag `a` by default is `display: inline`.
If you are applying styles to an  element that contains flow elements or any other elements that are represented in CSS as display: block, you should set the  itself to a proper block container type such as `block` or `inline-block` for its layout to work as intended.

Comment: adding display:"inline-block" to `a` solved it, but I don't understand your explanation why...